# Flash recommended Frame Rate - 2012

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame-rate

What is the recommended FPS(Frame rate) to use in flash applications?

Both for games and for simple applications.

- Let's assume that even simple applications are yet flash applications and they do use animations.

Answer (score 7):

There's no absolute answer to this question, but I will chime in with my approach.

Banner ads: 18fps

Applications: 32fps

High-end animations: 60fps

Games: Depends on the overhead. Ideally you test your game out and continuously push your FPS higher until you start to see lag.

Comment: This is about as close as you're going to get to an answer. There is no recommendation. It depends on what the application is and how much is going on. If you have a thousand DisplayObjects on the stage, you're not going to get 60fps (unless they are cached as bitmap and even then it is iffy). Decide what the application needs, what it can handle, and choose the best option